# Check if button has been submitted

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

i have a page with multiple forms like this: (all of them have different names

```
 <form method="post" name="form1">
    <input type="text>
    <input type="text>
    <input type="text>
    <input type="text>
    <button type="submit" name="button1" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary glyphicons circle_ok"><i></i>Save changes</button>
 </form>
```

This is the code i'm using to check which form is submitted:

```
if(IsPost && !Request["button1"].IsEmpty()) {  

}
```

the code above  only works if i submit the form through an `<input type="submit" name="button">`
i wanted to know if there's any way to know which form is submitted with a button type=submit (the one that's in the form i posted above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the value of the a `<button>` element is not posted. You could add a `hidden` field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formname" value="myform" />
```

Then check for this in your code:

```
if(IsPost && Request["formname"] == "myform") {  

}
```